# return value was give as return -1, but output is displayed as none

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, return-value, binary-search

this is Binary search program```

when the number doesn't exist a return value -1 is what expected followed by output statement will be displayed.but here I don't no why return value is none.can anyone please explain why this is happening.

```
def binary_serch(arr,element,r,l):
    if r>l:
        mid=l+(r-l)//2
        if arr[mid]==element:
            return mid
        if arr[mid]>element:
            return binary_serch(arr,element,mid+1,l)
        elif arr[mid]<element:
            return binary_serch(arr,element,mid-1,l)
        else:
            return -1
arr=[1,2,3,4,5]
element=6
result=binary_serch(arr,element,len(arr)-1,0)
num=len(arr)
print(result)
if result<num-1:
   print("Element is present at index ",result)
else:
    print("not found")
```

Comment: `binary_serch` returns `None` when `r <= l`.

Comment: There's also the problem that you never change `l`, only `r`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The only time you need to return `-1` is when `r < l`. Otherwise (with some careful handling of `mid`), you can ensure that every recursive call will eventually lead to `arr[mid] == element` being true, or `r < l`.

Comment: @chepner thank you for responding this is the first question I posted :)                      so I made three mistakes here    1. the cause of this error was an alignment issue else: return -1 is aligned incorrectly.     2. the second issue is with the L value as you said.   3. is with  the last if the condition      \\   if result!=-1:     this condition works \\

Answer (score 0):

In binary_search method there is a condition: `if r > l` that need `else` command.
Also it's better change `if arr[mid]>element` to `elif arr[mid]>element`.

I suggest you see this code and compare it with your code:

```
   def binary_search(arr, x):
    low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1
    mid = 0

    while low <= high:

        mid = (high + low) // 2

        # If x is greater, ignore left half
        if arr[mid] < x:
            low = mid + 1

        # If x is smaller, ignore right half
        elif arr[mid] > x:
            high = mid - 1

        # means x is present at mid
        else:
            return mid

    # If we reach here, then the element was not present
    return -1


# Test array
arr = [ 2, 3, 4, 10, 40 ]
x = 10

# Function call
result = binary_search(arr, x)

if result != -1:
    print("Element is present at index", str(result))
else:
    print("Element is not present in array")
```